# $viewContentLoaded Check if it's Successful

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-view

I wanted to ask about $viewContentLoaded... I'm building an Ionic app, and wanted to implement $ionicLoading, so that before the content is loaded, it shows a loading icon.The following is the line of code that is in my controller:

```
$ionicLoading.show({
 template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'+
        '</br></br><p>Loading...</p>',
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 300,
    showDelay: 0
  });

   $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function()
  {
    $timeout(function () {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      }, 2000);
  });
```

This works because I used the $timeout, but I wanted to to stop the $ionicLoading when the page has Loaded the content.

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Using `$timeout` ensures that a new $digest cycle is executed just after your code. Did you try without specifying a delay (instead of 2000) ? (default delay is 0). I feel like it will work too.

Otherwise, I'd recommend to use [Ionic Views' LifeCycle Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/), like `$ionicView.enter` which sounds appropriate for your need.

Comment: I think that's the one I needed... Thanks, I'll give it a go

Comment: Please let us know if this worked for you :-). Ionic Views' lifecycle events are clearly underused and I guess it's a pain for many developers!

Comment: So I tried it out, but it didn't work because with my app... I used an Ng-view, So it doesn't implement the $ionicView code at all...